# Get appsettings.json values in service .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have `appsettings.json` file where I want to declare paths to files.

`"Paths": {
    "file": "C:/file.pdf"
  }`

I want to access this value in my service, I try it to do like this:

```
public class ValueService: IValueService
{
    IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public MapsService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }


    public string generateFile()
    {

           var path = Configuration["Paths:file"] ;
    }

}
```

however I get null values for `var path`

`Startup.cs` file has `appsettings.json` declared as it takes connection string from there. Is it possible to access these values outside `startup.cs` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should register Configuration in ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to include `IConfiguration` seperately, it should already be included (in `AddMvc`?)

Comment: @STDMP actually, AddMvc just registers MVC middleware, not configuration

Answer (score 2):

You can see my [code here](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/Extension/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L294-L300) for detail. Basically I want to read email setting and the structure of my email setting look like this

```
"EmailSettings": {
    "MailServer": "",
    "MailPort": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Password": "",
    "SenderName": "",
    "Sender": "",
    "SysAdminEmail": ""
  }
```

Then I will need to define a class like this to hold all of information in appSetting

```
 public class EmailSettings
    {
        public string MailServer { get; set; }
        public int MailPort { get; set; }
        public string SenderName { get; set; }
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string SysAdminEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally I inject into my service class or whatever you want

```
private readonly IOptions<EmailSettings> _emailSetting;

public EmailSender(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSetting)
{
    _emailSetting = emailSetting;
}
```

then call

```
var something = _emailSetting.Value.SenderName
```

Email sender file can be found [here](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Email/EmailSender.cs)

If you have any question just let me know.

** Note this example help you read appSetting inside service class like class library or we can access appsetting data from outside main mvc app.