# Get Value from appsetting.json in class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some appsetting.json below

```
{
  "MyConfig": {
    "FolderAnnouncement": "Duyuru\\",
    "BaseMediaUrl": "D:\\YoungTalent\\YTPanel\\YTPanel\\wwwroot\\images\\"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySqlCon": "Server=localhost;Database=kariyer_portal;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;",
    "MsSqlCon": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=kariyer_portal;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And I have one class MyConfig.

```
namespace YTPanel.Models.Model
{
    public interface ITest { string GetFolders(string param); }
    public class MyConfig: ITest
    {
        public MyConfig(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;


        public string BaseMediaUrl { get; set; }
        public string FolderAnnouncement { get; set; }

        public string GetFolders(string param)
        {

            string here = Configuration["MyConfig:" + param];
            return here; 
        }
    }   
}
```

I want to call this class from another class

```
MyConfig conf;
  private  string SaveAnnouncement(IFormFile file=null,string base64=null)
        {
            string path = conf.GetFolders("FolderAnnouncement");
            string imageUrl = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var mediaPath = conf.GetFolders("BaseMediaUrl");
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var imagePath = mediaPath + path + imageUrl+extension;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64))
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
                File.WriteAllBytes(imagePath, bytes);  
            }
            else
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
            return  imageUrl+extension;

        }
```

I added below to ConfigureServices in Startup.

`services.AddSingleton<ITest, MyConfig>();`

I can't reach the data . How can I solve this problem.
I want to reacj appsetting json in one class and I use this class iin any classes I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say that you "can't reach the data," what does that literally mean? Is it throwing an exception, or something else?

Comment: @ScottHannen it returns null

Comment: if you want to access appsetting file without dependency refer this comment it will be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147072/3595964

Comment: You can see accept answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986497/get-appsettings-json-values-in-service-net-core/51006614#51006614

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There really is no need to be passing `IConfiguration` around. The framework already has built in features that allow you to bind an object model from values in setting

Create a simple class to hold your configuration.

```
public class MyConfig {
    public string BaseMediaUrl { get; set; }
    public string FolderAnnouncement { get; set; }
}
```

Setup your class in ConfigureServices in Startup.

```
//bind object model from configuration
MyConfig myConfig = Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig").Get<MyConfig>();

//add it to services
services.AddSingleton(myConfig);
```

And inject your strongly typed configuration class where it is needed

```
private readonly MyConfig conf;

//Constructor
public AnnouncementService(MyConfig config) {
    this.conf = config;
}

private async Task<string> SaveAnnouncement(IFormFile file = null, string base64 = null) {
    string path = conf.FolderAnnouncement;
    string imageUrl = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var mediaPath = conf.BaseMediaUrl;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    var imagePath = mediaPath + path + imageUrl+extension;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64)) {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        File.WriteAllBytes(imagePath, bytes);  
    } else {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create)) {
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
    return  imageUrl+extension;
}
```

Note how the *magic strings* are no longer needed. You can access the desired configuration values via the properties.

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Comment: Nice and simple way to deserialize appsettings.json to object. Somehow all the other examples I found so far on the web looked so complex.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @nkosi’s answer, the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) works well for this:

```
services.Configure<MyConfig>(configuration.GetSection(“MyConfig”));
```

...

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private MyConfig _options;

    public SomeClass(IOptions<MyConfig> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    private async Task<string> SaveAnnouncement(IFormFile file = null, string base64 = null)
    {
        string path = _options.FolderAnnouncement;
        ...
    }
}
```

There are additional variants available if you need to catch live changes to `appsettings.json`; see the link.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would inject your MyTest class (by interface) and use it like this:

```
public class AnnouncementSaver {

  private ITest config;
  public AnnouncementSaver(ITest config) {
    // inject it
    this.config = config;
  }

  private string SaveAnnouncement (IFormFile file = null, string base64 = null) {
    // use it
    config.GetFolders("FolderAnnouncement");
  }

}
```